# how to split string with (|) from a text file in mapreduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to write a mapreduce program which says to find the occurrence of every tv unit sold.
I/P ex-
Samsung|Optima|14|Madhya Pradesh|132401|14200
Onida|Lucid|18|Uttar Pradesh|232401|16200
Akai|Decent|16|Kerala|922401|12200
Lava|Attention|20|Assam|454601|24200
Zen|Super|14|Maharashtra|619082|9200

Below is the mapreduce code that I have written-
Mapper-

```
public class TotalUnitMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> {   
Text tvname;
//IntWritable unit; 
public void setup(Context context){     
    tvname = new Text();
    //  unit = new IntWritable();
}   
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException{       
    String[] lineArray2 = value.toString().split("|");      
    if(!lineArray2[0].contains("NA") || (!lineArray2[1].contains("NA"))){
            tvname.set((lineArray2[0]));
            IntWritable unit = new IntWritable(1);
            context.write(tvname,unit);
        }   
}}
```

Reducer-
    public class TotalUnitReducer extends Reducer {

```
public void reduce(Text tvname, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException,InterruptedException{
    int sum = 0;
    for (IntWritable value : values){
        sum+= value.get();
    }
    context.write(tvname, new IntWritable(sum));
}}
```

Driver-

```
public class TotalUnit {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf, "Assignment 3.3-2");
    job.setJarByClass(TotalUnit.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);      
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);     
    job.setMapperClass(TotalUnitMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(TotalUnitReducer.class);        
    job.setNumReduceTasks(2);        
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0])); 
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));      
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}}
```

However I am getting O/P as this-

```
A       1
O       4
S       7
L       3
N       1
Z       2
```

Only the first letters of TV Names are getting printed, I am not sure why. Is something wrong with Split ?
Please help as I am a beginner in Hadoop.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape that parameter:

```
String d = "Samsung|Optima|14|Madhya Pradesh|132401|14200 Onida|Lucid|18|Uttar Pradesh|232401|16200 Akai|Decent|16|Kerala|922401|12200 Lava|Attention|20|Assam|454601|24200 Zen|Super|14|Maharashtra|619082|9200";

String[] lineArray2 = value.toString().split("\\|");      
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineArray2));
```